# Using a non-kosher toaster oven

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, appliances

What is the permissible way to use a non-kosher toaster oven? My thought process was that, when cooking milk in a meat oven, the covering of the dish and the rack makes it acceptable.

Would covering the food and the rack be enough to cook in a non-kosher toaster oven?

Does the fact that it's a toaster oven change anything?

Comment: AFAIK you're incorrect about milk in a meat oven. CYLOR of course, but if I'm not mistaken the surface you put the milk on must also not have had a meat pot on it, so should be covered by e.g. foil. (We don't rely _l'chat'chila_ that taste doesn't transfer between surfaces without moisture.)

Comment: Note also that toaster ovens are very hard to clean completely and that any answer you get below, if it doesn't specify, *might* be assuming the oven's clean. In any event, as always, CYLOR rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Comment: Double-wrapping in foil suffices for airplanes and at least some catered events I've been to (where the venue wasn't kosher but my meal was).  I don't know what would make toaster ovens special, though.

Comment: @msh210 - Definitely, I just wanted to see if anyone was familiar with the issue. Regarding the milk, you are correct, the surface is important. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @msh210 ["The final issue that must be addressed when using an oven for dairy and meat is the oven rack. It is axiomatic that ta’am (taste) does not pass between vessels without liquid. For this reason, if a dry hot meat pot came into contact with a dry dairy pot , both remain kosher. (Rama, Yoreh Dayah 92:8). As such, Rav Moshe Feinstein (ibid and Igros Moshe Yoreh Dayah III:10) permits the use of the same oven rack for dairy and meat pots."](http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/is_your_oven_kosher_what_every_kosher_cook_must_know) The article does go on to give other opinions.

Comment: That was LeChateḥilah, btw. The dissenting opinion says only BeDi'Avad, as you suggested above.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40194/3342 Kol tuv.

Answer (score 3):

R Yitzchok Yaakov Fuchs (in his book [Hakashrut](https://www.eichlers.com/hakashrut-rav-yitzchok-yaakov-fuchs-hardcover.html), p. 665) writes

> Baking ovens and toaster ovens that were used for meat and dairy foods
>   **and even for prohibited foods** may be used to bake or warm up kosher food **on the condition that the food placed inside is wrapped
>   hermetically in two wrappings.**
>
> In any event only kosher baking tins or disposable ones may be used
>   and not the banking tins and dishes that are inside.

The difference between a regular oven and a toaster oven is that

> a toaster oven has limited space inside with the heating element in
>   the rook of the appliance exposed. While it is in use it tends to get
>   dirty and it is very difficult to clean completely

Comment: Interestingly, this question had 1000 views and no answer