# Using a non-kosher rotating pizza oven

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, appliances

A countertop rotating pizza oven has a turntable on which pizza is placed. It has two heating elements: one heats from below the turntable, like a hot plate. A heating element above broils a section of the pizza at a time as it rotates. There are no enclosed spaces that would trap steam as in a traditional oven or [toaster oven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/using-a-non-kosher-toaster-oven).

Can a non-kosher pizza oven of this type (such as at a workplace or common area) be used for kosher food? If so, what steps would be necessary?

[Here is a PDF of a manual with diagrams.](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/d9/d9d73a9c-4eae-4563-81ca-54c83edab14f.pdf)

(CYLOR)

Comment: Kodem kol. Isn't זעה something that isn't rlly bolaya?

Answer (score 1):

The entire discussion hinges on certain assumptions, the primary ones being that steam or condensation is an issue in this case and that steel/aluminum is *boleya*. In addition to this, the discussion of steam being an issue is in an enclosed oven (both vented and non-vented models) which seems would not be an issue in this case, being that it is fully open (cf. `Arokh HaShulhan 92:55).

While it is true that the Rama in the Shulhan `Arukh (92:8) is *mahmir* regarding steam (*zeyah*) relying on a *teshuvah* of the Rosh (20:26) [who quotes a Mishnah in Masekheth Makhshirim (2:2)], the fact is that the *sugya* in the *Gemara* which discusses the whole issue of an oven (b.Pesahim 76b, see also y.Terumoth 10:2) and kosher and non-kosher foods being cooked in it does not even mention *zeyah* as an issue, concludes that *reyha* (aroma) is *law miltha* (not a halakhic issue), and is only discussing kosher and non-kosher meat ***simultaneously***.

Also, as is common in Ashkenazi *pesiqath halakhah*, there is an equivocation between the laws of *hekhsher/tumah wa-ttaharah* with the laws of *kashruth*. While there is some overlap, they are definitely separate, as anyone who reads *Hilkhoth Tumath Okhalin* and *Hilkhoth Ma'akhaloth Asuroth* will be able to easily ascertain. Thus, the reason why Rosh has to bring a proof from m.Makhshirim regarding the condensation in a bath house being *tamei* is because the whole idea of steam is not considered an issue within the scope of *kashruth* until the equivocation of the two areas of *halakhah* at a much later time in Jewish history. Hazal makes no such claim in the sources which they left to us.

As for the types of materials which are subject to *beli`uth* (absorption), the *Gemara* is discussing *klei heres* (porous pottery/adobe) and not metal at all. Many today hold that metal (stainless steel/aluminum) is not *boleya* and thus not subject to these laws anyhow, except by those who feel it is necessary to be *mahmir*.

All this being said, I would say that *le'aniyuth da`ati* that all that needs to be done to use this pizza oven is a thorough cleaning to remove outer food residue (particles, grease, oil, etc.), and perhaps a lining of the pan where the pizza actually sits with foil as a caution.

I hope that this helps. Kol tuv.

Comment: cf. Mishkenoth Yaaqov 34 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1095&pgnum=234

Comment: If I am understanding the teshuvah correctly as I quickly read it, your reference here is to both reinforce my comments about the confusion between tumah wa-ttaharah and kashruth as well as to subtly remind me that my comments regarding "Ashkenazi pesiqath halakhah" in this regard need to be balanced since the "Mishkenoth Yaaqov" was written by Rav Ya'aqov ben Aharon, the Rav of Karlin and one of the foremost students of Rav Hayim Volozhiner z"l (both of whom were thoroughly Ashkenazi).

Comment: Although we may simply be seeing the same departure from standard Ashkenazi pesiqath halakhah that was first and most famously found in the halakhic writings of the Gr"a (e.g. Ma`aseh Rav, Bi`ur HaGra al haShulhan `Arukh, et al), where he famously overturns minhaghim and pisqei din from Ashkenaz hundreds of years old. Anyway, I appreciate your reference and the opportunity to read something of which I was previously unaware. Todah Rabbah Rabbah. Kol tuv.

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82672/jewish/Koshering-Appliances-and-Utensils.htm) on koshering utensils, it seem that your rotating pizza oven most nearly approximates a broiler (at least from on top). Certainly the steam etc. from the cooking pizza must reach the upper heater.

Therefore I would think that the koshering method described there would be appropriate i.e.

> The Broiler
>
> As mentioned previously, the broiler pan and grill can be koshered
>   only by using direct heat, using a blowtorch, causing them to glow
>   red. This is necessary because non-kosher food may have been cooked
>   directly on the pan or grill. If this method is not feasible, the
>   simplest procedure is to replace the pan with a new pan and kosher the
>   empty broiler cavity by cleaning and setting it to broil for forty
>   minutes.

The removable baking pan of your apparatus equates to the broiler pan and you will have to  get the lower element hot for 40 mins or use a blowtorch on it and as you say CYLOR.

Comment: The steam from the pizza may reach the upper heater, but the steam from the upper heater certainly does not reach the pizza, since it is not enclosed. For this reason, I am not sure that this is an analogous situation to a broiler oven. Also, since the question relates to an appliance in a common area, it cannot be assumed to remain kosher. Would a foil covering suffice instead of replacing the turntable?

Answer (score 0):

The tray would require libun gamur because the heating element appears to be directly under the tray cooking the pizza. Instructions for libun gamur may be found [here (Purim-style source)](http://www.youtube.com/v/shMvpRebngc?version=3&start=25&end=28&autoplay=1&hl=en_US&rel=0) I don't think the upper heating element requires anything at all because it does not have any contact with the food.