# Do toasters become fleishig or milchig

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, do toasters which are used for either milchig or fleishig foods retain the status of  milchig or fleishig, and therefor forbidden to use for fleishig items if it is milchig, and forbidden to use for milchig items while fleishig? Or no, do toasters not absorb the taste of milchig or fleishig food put in it?

Comment: How would you kasher a toaster?

Comment: Are you talking about this kind of toaster? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44681/toasters-in-motels-cabins

Comment: Or a toaster oven? A toaster oven is just like a regular oven. If you don’t put food directly on it, or you have different grates, then you clean it between use, and maybe burn it out and use it. Until 30 years ago most homes only had one oven